# How can I find an item in an array and remove it

Tags: typescript, ngrx-store, angular15

I'm trying to remove an item inside the _state[] by comparing the id of the item to be removed. I used filter but when trying to call this action throw the store all the values are still showing.

```
export const bookReducer = createReducer(
  initialCtion,
  on(book.retrievedBook, (_state, { book } ) => book),
  on(book.removeBook., (_state, { book } ) =>  _state.filter((id) => id.id != book) || [])
);
```

Below is showing the book object that is passed down to the book arg shown above.

```
book: Book= {
id: "2342342",
name: "case1"
}

onRemove(_action: Book){
  const book= _book.id;
  this.store.dispatch(ApiBooks.removeBook({book}))
}
```

Comment: Use `filter` instead of `find`?

Comment: I did but didn't work

Comment: `id.id != id`? How do you think that the interpreter can tell apart two different objects for which you use the same name? The argument of the filtering function (`(id) => ...`) hides the parameter `id` of the outer function (`(_state, { id }) => ...`).

Comment: It's was wrongly typed when posting the issue, I just updated it, thanks